# Why is my baked normal result is so whirly and jaggy?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, texture-baking, normal-map

im trying to apply highpoly to low poly model but the result of it is:

[image]

here is the original highpoly version, how the result was suppose to look:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any major differences between highpoly and normal map, they both have edges on the surface. Did you enable smooth shading for the highpoly before baking?

Comment: take a look at the lines carved on the object on both images, the first one look jagged.

Comment: Welcome to blender.se. Although I can also see the "jagged lines" you are refering to, please carefully read all of Mr Zaks comment. **Did you enable smooth shading for the highpoly before baking?**

Comment: well now i did but it doesn't seem to do any difference.. you are referring to smooth shading in dyntopo, am I correct?